# okhttp3 : writing to MySQL from Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, okhttp

I've spent a long time now trying to figure out how to write to MySQL on a web server from my Android application. I plan to execute an update in a table with data comming from Android. I have a PHP page that seems to work, at least when I call it from HTTRequester module in Firefox.

HttpRequest is set with a parameter called "request" and a value for it :

```
{"Temp":"34.4","McsObservation":4,"McsSensation":4,"Id_day":9,"DateCycle":"2015-12-01","Id_profile":"672"}
```

When I submit a POST to my php, from there, the table is updated.

However, in Android when I execute the following code, I got the message *"Unfortunately MyApplication has stopped"*.

**temp_quick.java** includes:

```
btnUpdateTemp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         //MyPostTemp.Post
        PostTemperature quick_temp = new PostTemperature();
        String json = quick_temp.QuickTempJson(42, "36.66");
        outputResult.setText(json);
        String response = null;
        try {
            response = quick_temp.post("http://MyWeb.fr/Inverseo/insert_mesure.php", json);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       System.out.println(response);
```

Then in **PostTemperature.java**:

```
package com.inverseo.marc.t372lematin;

//test HttpURLConnection
import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class PostTemperature {
// ex with OKHttp

public static final MediaType JSON
        = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(body)
                    .build();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return response.body().string();
        }

        String QuickTempJson(Integer id_day, String temp) {
            return "{\"request\":{" +
                        "\"Temp\":\"" + temp + "\","
                        + "\"McsObservation\":1,"
                        + "\"McsSensation\":2,"
                        + "\"Id_day\":" + id_day + ","
                        + "\"DateCycle\":\"2015-11-03\","
                        + "\"Id_profile\":\"1394\"}"
                        + "}" ;
    }
```

The logcat I got is the following:

```
01-25 22:00:25.364 1924-1924/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.inverseo.marc.myapplic, PID: 1924
     android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
         at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
         at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
         at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
         at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
         at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:173)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:139)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:81)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:127)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
         at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:240)
         at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198)
         at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)
         at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57)
         at com.inverseo.marc.t372lematin.PostTemperature.post(PostTemperature.java:37)
         at com.inverseo.marc.t372lematin.temp_quick$4.onClick(temp_quick.java:322)
         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance for any clue to make this run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key lies in the exception: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. You can't, in Android world, make network calls on the main thread. Since you're calling `post()` from an `OnClickListener`, you're making an network call on the main thread. You need to move your call to `post()` onto a background thread. You can do this by using a `Thread`, an `AsyncTask` (basically a nice, easy way to perform background threading on Android), or OkHttp's `Callback`. There's an example here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes.

I've never used OkHttp directly, but here's an example of how to use their async api:

```
String json = "<YOUR JSON STRING>";
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://MyWeb.fr/Inverseo/insert_mesure.php")
        .post(RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), json))
        .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
    // Request failed
  }

  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
    // Handle whatever comes back from the server
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. I'll try this tomorrow

Comment: I found a nice example on [link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-mysql-tutorial-to-perform-basic-crud-operation/)